# How to register rhythmbox service on system dbus?

Tags: d-bus, rhythmbox

Installed rhythmbox and rhythmbox-plugins but there is no org.Rhythmbox in the list of available dbus services. To view the list I use:

```
dbus-send --system            \
  --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus \
  --type=method_call          \
  --print-reply               \
  /org/freedesktop/DBus       \
  org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rhythmbox needs the MPRIS plugin enabled (use the plugins window to enable the plugin)

[image: pic]

Modern Rhythmbox versions ([2.90.1 and later](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/rhythmbox-devel/2012-January/msg00013.html)) exposes a session dbus entry called "org.gnome.Rhythmbox3" when Rhythmbox is actually running.  To see this slightly alter your dbus command:

```
dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus --type=method_call --print-reply /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames
```

Alternatively just use the mpris interface as explained in [this excellent Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771477/how-to-continuously-monitor-rhythmbox-for-track-change-using-python-revisited).

If you use the application d-feet then this clearly displays the objects exposed by the mpris interface:

[image: pic]

Comment: But i use Ubuntu with KDE.  I think in dbus list i should see something like org.mpris.MediaPlayer.Rhythmbox. So the question is:  How to activate dbus mpris service? Install latest version of DBus?

Comment: you shouldnt need to install a newer dbus - I dont use KDE but I understand mpris should be exposed - check using d-feet as explained in the edit.